# Unauthorized user getting added to GCP roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-iam

When adding a specific user (usera@company.com) to an editor role in a project (any project), usera@company.com does not get added. Instead userz@gmail.com gets added.
This happens no matter if we use the GCP console, SDK (gcloud cli / Terraform) etc.

The interesting thing is that userz is the son of usera. That’s the only commonality. They do not work at the same company, nor do they share laptops, etc.

Any idea?

I can add redacted screenshots if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cloud Console to add members, Console uses Google People API to autocomplete the names. This list is drawn from the account's (that you're using in Console) list of Contacts.

> **NOTE** If you open e.g. Chrome's DevTools while in Console and autocompleting on an email, on the Network tab you will see calls made to `/v2/people/autocomplete` and you can review the response that the Console is receiving. This may show the mismatch too.

I **suspect** that you've a mismatch in this account's Google Contacts that's presenting user@company.com but actually has userz@gmail.com as that contact's (perhaps default) email address.

Open Contact, search for the contact and see whether the mismatch is evident.

Alternatively, use `gcloud` (Cloud SDK) to issue the command:

```sh
PROJECT="[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]"
ACCOUNT="usera@company.com"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=user:${ACCOUNT} \
--role=roles/editor
```